# How check for ID existence using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have a line of code similar to below:

```
var name = $('#input-name').attr("value");
```

However, the id 'input-name' is not guaranteed to exist.  How do I check for its existence so that the assignment does not throw an error?

Comment: Just to add, if it *is* an <input>, you can simply use .val()

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
if ($('#input-name').length) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: @ScottE : nice tip to solve same problem for me! thx for this :) just BTW, it seems you added a trailing ; which is not necessary ?

Answer (score 3):

Check for .length or .size() on the object. The select won't fail, jQuery will always return an object.

Answer (score 1):

In my test the assignment didn't cause an error, it simply returned `undefined`.

In which case the solution would be the following:

```
var name = $('#input-name').attr("value");
if (name) {
  // blah blah
}
```

Or maybe:

```
var name = $('#input-name').attr("value") || 'defaultValue';
```

... if that makes sense in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
var name;
if ($('#input-name').length > 0)   
name= $('#input-name').attr("value");
```